# Can multiple records be generated depending on a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am a newbie when it comes to SQL so please forgive my ignorance regarding this question. I have a database that contains a `Passenger`, `Booking`, `Booking_Details` and  `Ticket` tables.

In the Booking table i have an attribute called `noOfPassengers`. I want to implement a scenario where a passenger booking tickets for his family such that one booking ID (in the booking table) will generate multiple records in the passenger and ticket tables depending on if the `numberOfPassenger` is > 1.

How do i accomplish this in SQL? I am aware that some joins will be required between the tables but am not sure about the structure of the SQL command.

Comment: This would normally be done either at the application level or via a stored procedure that uses a `while` loop.

Comment: it would be better if you show us the ERD...

Comment: You can generate multiple rows via an `INSERT` / `SELECT` where the latter can or cannot be part of a `JOIN` ... would you like me show you an example of each?

Comment: Hi Drew,Yes i'd appreciate it if you can show me the examples of each.

Answer (score 0):

You would do that in php not sql. Below is an example:

```
<?php
//connect to dbh
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
/**
 * @param array $data 
 */
function addBooking($data)
{
    global $db;
    $booking_id = false;
    //add any other fields you have too.
    $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Bookings (name,date)
    VALUES (:name,:date);');
    $sth->bindParam(':name', $data['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(':date', $data['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    // and bind any other fields you have.
    if ($sth->execute()) {
        $booking_id = intVal($db->lastInsertId());
        $sql = '';
        $failed = false;
        foreach ($data['passengers'] as $key => $passenger) {
            //add any other fields you have too.
            $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Passengers (name,booking_id)
    VALUES (:name,:booking_id);';
            $sth->bindParam(':name', $passenger['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':date', $booking_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            // and bind any other fields you have.
            $sth->execute();
        }
    }
    return $booking_id;
}

function getBooking($booking_id)
{
    global $db;
    //add any other fields you have too.
    $sth = $db->prepare('
    SELECT 
        Bookings.name as booking_name, 
        Bookings.date as booking_date, 
        Passengers.* FROM Bookings
    RIGHT JOIN Passengers on Bookings.id = Passengers.booking_id
    WHERE Bookings.id = :id;');
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $booking_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $booking = array(
        'name' => $result[0]['booking_name']]],
        'name' => $result[0]['booking_date']]],
        'passengers' => array()
    );
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if (isset($row['name'])) {
            $booking['passengers'][] = array(
                'name' => $row['name']
            );
        }

    }
    return $booking;
}

/**
 * Usage
 */
$data = array(
    'name' => 'Taxi',
    //other data here too
    'passengers' => array(
        'name' => 'Antony'
        //other data here too
    )
);
$booking_id = addBooking($data);

$booking = getBooking($booking_id);
```

So you would need something like this for you table structure

```
Passengers
id | name | booking_id 

Bookings
id | name | date
```

You don't actually need to store the number of passengers, you can find that out easily using a query;

Also this code might have errors. But you should be able to use it as a starting point.

Comment: @barudo. Where can i post the ERD for you to see my tables structure? I'm looking for an ''add attachment'' link or button but can't see any.

Comment: @Jockfaire I've updated my answer to show an actual example, you would just need to add the actual columns

Comment: Thanks Antony. Is it necessary or appropriate to have the booking id in the passengers table when i already have the passenger id as a foreign key in the bookings table?

Comment: If you had passender_id in the booking table you can only assign one passenger to a booking. So for you requirements it is necessary.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I was thinking of normalization of the tables but i suppose that for me to implement the scenario of multiple passengers on one booking i would need to denormalize the passengers table. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What you have is a hasMany relationship between Booking and Passenger and a hasOne relationship between Passenger and Booking. This explains it well. Your models would be Passenger and Booking: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Actually if you read this: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: Thanks for the links Antony. They're much appreciated. I am now realizing that my ERD will have to be revised..again......on the nth attempt....arghhhhh...